# Cordova GLOBAL is not defined when running on Android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I have setup a Cordova app with react following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@pshubham/using-react-with-cordova-f235de698cc3).
When I try to run it on a physical android device using `cordova run android -- --livereload` The app is not compiled and not sent to the device, the only output I get is:

```bash
cordova run android -- --livereload
Successfully built!
GLOBAL is not defined
```

This is the verbose output of the command:

```bash
GLOBAL is not defined
ReferenceError: GLOBAL is not defined
    at Object.isLiveReloadActivated (/Users/ivan/Desktop/MasterThesis/Test2/cordovaReact/plugins/cordova-plugin-livereload/lib/utils/helpers.js:94:5)
    at Object.module.exports.isLiveReloadActive (/Users/ivan/Desktop/MasterThesis/Test2/cordovaReact/plugins/cordova-plugin-livereload/lib/index.js:21:17)
    at module.exports (/Users/ivan/Desktop/MasterThesis/Test2/cordovaReact/plugins/cordova-plugin-livereload/lib/postEmulateRunHook.js:19:13)
    at runScriptViaModuleLoader (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:157:32)
    at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:136:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:108:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

What is GLOBAL and how can I fix this error in order to get my app to compile and live reload?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your index.html file

```
 <script>const global = globalThis;</script>
```

Comment: Still shows the same error unfortunately